# How close is functional testing related to security testing?

Tags: self-education, certification

I am working as a functional software tester now.I want to make a head start in the field of security testing such as security testing of web applications etc.I know this is a subjective question,but I want to know whether there exists such a career path?

I am planing to take CEH and then proceed with penetration testing as my main scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The career path most definitely exists if you make it for yourself.  I know of a few testers who have gone on to purely security.  Functional approaches and security approaches can often overlap each other, and many of those who I speak with in the security field are grateful for  their previous test experience.

After a time however, I've found that often functional tests and security tests tend to overlap and blend in with each other in agile-ish environments.  About the only time that I actually think of "security" tests is when I've been asked to do penetration tests or run vulnerability scans.  Otherwise, it's just testing.

Short answer - absolutely, they **can** be closely related.

Comment: Thanks for your input :).It would be of great help to me.

Answer (score -2):

This can help:-
http://www.infosectoday.com/Articles/SecurityTesting.htm

Comment: Generally, we expect answers to have more than just a link. They should have insight directed at the question being asked. It's fine to support your answer with references, and it's strongly encouraged to isolate the key points in your answer and say "for further reading, check out this and this ". But just a link is strongly discouraged.